# CMake example code in Visual Studio encounters GDB connection issues when debugging on a remote Linux platform

Tags: linux, visual-studio, cmake, remote-debugging

I need assistance troubleshooting an issue that has been troubling me for a week,

When building a cross-platform Linux program using CMake in Visual Studio, an error message window pops up during runtime with the message "Unable to start debugging. Unable to establish a connection to GDB. Debug output may contain more information."

After clicking "OK", a new error message window appears with the message "Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT:0x80004004(E_ABORT))."

The Linux platform information:

ubuntu18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver) x86_64 Nvidia GPU Server
kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic
lldb version 6.0.0
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 10.2-0ubuntu1~18.04~2) 10.2
cmake version 3.22.1
ninja 1.8.2
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
The cross-platform log:

[image]

Please assist me in identifying and resolving this issue.